# Executing different queries depending on case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a column called 'Measure', which contains multiple values. When the value of this columns is 'Majors', I want to execute the following:

```
select *
from students;
```

And when the value is anything else, I want to execute:

```
select distinct *
from students;
```

I have used CASE statements in the past to return a single value. How can they be made to return an entire query? Alternatively, how can this problem be approached without CASE?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give a try at this. Basicly, it gives you all the results for Majors and then adds up the other results.

```
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE Measure = 'Majors'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM students
WHERE Measure <> 'Majors'
```

Comment: 'Measure' is actually a prompt, so the user gets to choose any one value of Measure. So, the UNION will give the complete set of results regardless of the value of 'Measure'.

Comment: You can use a variable like this :

Declare @variable Varchar (@name and then Type) and use that variable in the querry

Comment: Set @variable = 'something'